# Please revert migration

Tags: support, migration

Regarding my question:

[How to download all videos with yt-dlp from a youtube channel after the redesign?](https://superuser.com/questions/1752396/how-to-download-all-videos-with-yt-dlp-from-a-youtube-channel-after-the-redesign?noredirect=1)

To summarize, I think it was a erroneous migration. I flagged it to try to get it back and it was marked as helpful, but no action taken.

> I don't believe the migration was warranted. This is not a question about using Youtube, the webapp, this is about using a command line utility yt-dlp that downloads content from Youtube. Webapps doesn't even have that tag around while SuperUser does. It already has a home here.

[yt-dlp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/yt-dlp) derived from [youtube-dl](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/youtube-dl)

I have an answer to the question and full explanation why my tests were failing, but I can't post it (and considering the question is already off-topic at the migrated-to site, I don't want to post there).

Can this be undone?

Comment: Side note: the last thing I would want to have happen is the migrated-to site deems it off-topic (which it is) and _I_ get dinged for it...

Comment: It can only be be done by the target site. Their mods have to close it as off-topic which will send it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done, I have closed the question on WebApps which has rejected the migration